# 'MongoClient' object is not iterable error

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I'm trying to upload a large json file into MongoDB Atlas in python3. Here is my code

```
def connectMongoDb():
    username = urllib.parse.quote_plus("test@gmail.com")
    password =urllib.parse.quote_plus("4-mmmm!")



   try:
       url = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://"+username+":"+password+"@realmcluster.vlout.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
     

     cluster= MongoClient(url)
     db = cluster["store"]
     collections = ["items"]

except Exception as e:
     print("connection error ", str(e))
 try:
    with open('storeItems.json') as f:
        file_data = json.load(f)

     
        collections.insert_one(file_data)
        print(collections)

except Exception as e:
    print("writting error", str(e))
```

the error i keep getting are

> 'MongoClient' object is not iterable
> Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

how do i fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have already initialized the MongoClient constructor in the line
`url = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://"+username+":"+password+"@realmcluster.vlout.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")`  and so you don't need to do `cluster= MongoClient(url)`. Also it seems that in order to get a collection you need to do `collections = db["items"]`

Read the [documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for additional help.